# Clipping a VBO rendered with a shader

Tags: python, opengl

I'm developping a 2D game engine, using PyOpenGL.

For coherence with previous versions of my engine, that used SDL, the graphic elements are first stored in a VBO, with a 2D coordinate system where (0, 0) is top-left and (640, 448) is bottom-right (so y axis is reversed). Let's call it SDL-coordinates.

Since my graphics use palette effects, I rendered them with shaders. My vertex shader simply convert my 2D coordinate system to the [-1;1] cube.

Now, I need to clip the display. My first idea was to do it via the pixel shader, by sending all vertices outside the clipping zone to a point outside the [-1 ; 1] cube (I took (2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)) but it went wrong : it deformed squared tiles which had some of their edges outside the clipping zone but not all.

So I consider using glFrustum, but I don't understand in which coordinate system I must specify the params.

In fact, I tried to put more or less anything as parameters without noticing anything when running the code. What am I doing wrong ?

For the moment, my drawing routine looks like that :

```
def draw(self):
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D )
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 )
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.v_texture)

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_1D )
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 )

    shaders.glUseProgram(self.shaders_program)
    shaders.glUniform1i(self.texture_uniform_loc, 0)
    shaders.glUniform1i(self.palette_uniform_loc, 1)
    shaders.glUniform2f(self.offset_uniform_loc, 0, 0)
    shaders.glUniform4f(self.color_uniform_loc, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    # Draw layers
    for layer in self.layers: #[0:1]:
        layer.draw()

    shaders.glUseProgram( 0 )
    pygame.display.flip()
```

In class Layer:

```
def draw(self):
    glFrustum(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 1.0) # I tried anything here...

    # offset is an offset to add to coordinates (in SDL_coordinates)
    shaders.glUniform2f(self.vdp.offset_uniform_loc, self.x, self.y)
    # color is likely irrelevant here 
    shaders.glUniform4f(self.vdp.color_uniform_loc, *self.color_modifier)

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.palette.get_id())

    self.vbo.bind()

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 20, self.vbo)
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 20, self.vbo + 12)
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, len(self.vbo))

    self.vbo.unbind()
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

Note : I must say that I'm new to OpenGL. I learnt by reading tutorials and was quite confused with the 'old' and 'new' OpenGL.

I felt like frustum was more 'old' OpenGL, like many of tranformation matrix manipulation (most of it can be handled by vertex shaders). I may be totally wrong at that and glFrustum (or something else) may be unavoidable in my case. I'd like to read an article about what can be totally forgotten in 'old' OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using the built-in matrices (`gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` etc.) in your shaders, `glFrustum` won't do anything. If you aren't using those matrices, don't start using them now (you are correct that this is part of 'old' OpenGL).

It sounds like you want to use [`glScissor`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml) which defines a clipping rectangle in window coordinates (note that the origin of these is at the lower-left of the window). You have to enable it with `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`.

As far as articles about what can be totally forgotten in 'old' OpenGL: Googling "Modern OpenGL", or "OpenGL deprecated" should give you a few starting points.